# How to bypass return confirm () programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have timer function which clicks end test (submit) button after time gets over like this

```
 var dur = $ {
     Schedule.duration
 };
 dur = dur * 60 * 1000;
 setTimeout(function () {
     $('#endtest5').click();
 }, +dur);
```

and I also have confirmation function on same submit button, but I do not want to call confirmation function when time gets over, or when EndTest clicked programmatically, how do I do it?
My confirm function below -

```
<input align="left" type="submit" name="end" value="End Test" id="endtest5" class="myButton" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue')"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onClick` attribute and set `click` event handler with jQuery.
Then set a *flag* (`testing`) to determine whether the `click` was actually performed with a mouse or function:

```
var testing = false;

$('#endtest5').click(function(){
    if(!testing){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue');
    }
    testing = false;
});

var dur = $ {
    Schedule.duration
};
dur = dur * 60 * 1000;
setTimeout(function () {
    testing = true;
    $('#endtest5').click();
}, +dur);
```

Comment: its submit button so its submitting form even if i click cancel in confirmation box ...

Answer (score 1):

[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) always add the **isTrigger** property to the event object.

You can test this property in order to check if the event is triggered from another jQuery function (your timer, for instance).

If you need to prevent submit you can use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) testing [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) return value.

```js
//
// Remove the onclick inline event handler if you cannot do it by hand
//
$('#endtest5').removeAttr('onclick');


$('#endtest5').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.isTrigger !== undefined) {
        // if timer triggers this event do nothing
        return;
    }
    var retVal = confirm('Are you sure you want to continue');
    // if cancel....no submit
    if (retVal == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})


//
// simulate a timer click: nothing will happen...
//
$('#endtest5').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input align="left" type="submit" name="end" value="End Test" id="endtest5" class="myButton" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue')"/>
```

Comment: your previous answer worked fine , you also had forgotten return before  confirm. thank you.

Comment: @NinadGosavi return is useless because I use e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

move confirmation to a function and create a variable to check if test is completed or ended and then check that variable before running confirm.

Comment: i did that but return confirm dose not work when called from function . test gets ended anyway even if click cancel .         `   function End(){
 
 if (flag == 0)
  {
  //do nothing
  }
 else {
 return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue');
 }
} `